# Making eval run async code synchronously

Tags: javascript, eval

I am passing a javascript snippet as a string which gets called for an array of data (csv file). I want to eval the next row only after completing the first row:

CoffeeScript (gets compiled into javascript and run in a browser):

```
for row in rest
  map = makeMap header,row
  json = JSON.stringify map
  eval "((#{fn})(#{json}))"
```

Javascript Snippet (stored as string):

```
function(map) {
  console.log(map.customer_id);
  $.ajax("http://localhost:3000/data/" + map.customer_id,
         function(data) { console.log(data);});
}
```

How does one implement `done()` that is found in Jasmine BDD or other javascript testing frameworks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what framework that `$.ajax` function is from you might be able to pass a parameter to it to make the AJAX synchronous.

However, not all async functions have an option to turn into async mode. In that case, the only way to go is to have them call a callback (either hardcoded or as a parameter). Unfortunately, you will need to rewrite that for-loop into a recursive function (or use an async library that does that for you).

```
var i = 0;
function processItems(i){
   if(i >= rest.length){
      return whatToDoNext();
   }else{
      runMyAsyncCode(function(){
         proccessItems(i+1);
      })
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can't make javascript run synchronously without a lot of hassle. However, you can make it *appear* to run synchronously by, for example, using promises - objects which represent the eventual value returned by the function. You can read up on promises (called deferred objects in jquery) in the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

This is how an ajax handler using jquery deferred object would look like (notice the use of the `done` function)

```
$.ajax("http://localhost:3000/data/" + map.customer_id).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);});
});
```